# Policy of data generated using Plaid API or Yodlee

Tags: yodlee, banking, plaid

I'm working on a startup and we plan to use Plaid API or Yodlee for banking data aggregation ie credit history and previous transactions. I wanted to know about the data policy of these services from a fellow programmer who has worked on it. The sales guys give a pretty garbled view. 
My questions are mainly

1. If one of my users had previously given their data to these
   aggregators (ie maybe used Yodlee for mint) do they have to put in
   each of their bank login details again if they use my service or do
   they have a sort of user profile with which they can authorize my
   app to view the data stored in their service.
2. Does Plaid API/Yodlee use the data I generate for its own uses and
   do my users owe these data to these services and not me?
3. If I want to move out do they still hold my users data (the bank
   accounts they have signed up with)as a profile on their desk?

PS: I think this question follows SO's policy but feel free to correct me if not.